# Core Data under the hood memory usage

Tags: ios, core-data, memory-management

So I am a bit confused about the amount of copies core data keeps for every managed object. First it stores a copy in the row cache which it uses to fulfill faults. Then for every object it also keeps a snapshot of the unmodified object as well as the actual data for the object (assuming its not a fault). That's 3 copies for one object so I assume I am misunderstanding something. This would mean migrations would need 4 times the size of the objects in the original database as it also has to create a new destination stack. I assume core data is smart and may do things like copy-on-write under the hood and not create a snapshot unless the object is actually modified.

Could someone please explain what is wrong about my thought process? Also is it true that the row cache will be shared by different managed object contexts created from the same persistent coordinator, or is there a row cache for each context?